# jQuery load for <button> instead of href

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have a shopping cart which I am loading in to my own custom dashboard by using for eg a html page which loads the php shopping cart page in to my own html file.

```
$app->get('/cata-categories/?', function () use ($app) {   
           $app->render('cata-categories.html', [
               'page' => [
                   'author' =>         $app->site->author,
                   'title' =>          "Catagories",
                   'description' =>    "Catalogue Catagories.",
                   'alerts' =>         $app->alerts->getAndClearMessages()
               ]
           ]);  
        });
```

To get it working nicely I am loading links to pages on the shopping cart inside divs on pages of my own dashboard's pages.

```
<ol id="categories"></ol>

                <script>
                    $( "#categories" ).load( "../solutions/admin/index.php?route=catalog/category" );
                </script>
```

To keep everything within the dashboard, I make links on these shopping cart pages also open within the same div, I am using the load function as well.

The code to make href links load in the same div I am using is as follows:

```
$("#categories").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $("#categories").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I also have buttons to submit forms or which load / link to another page:
eg.

```
<button type="submit" form="form-category" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
```

I want that to load in the same div when these buttons and other buttons on that page are clicked just like a href link.

Basically my question is what do I use instead of .attr("href")?

Comment: If you want to submit forms without causing a page load, you would need to use AJAX. For that you'd need to use `$.post()`, `$.get()`, or `$.ajax()` (depending on your requirements) instead of `load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized where I was going wrong about it. The shopping cart has functions for validating forms / submissions etc and I just needed to use

```
$this->response->redirect('../../portal/cata-categories');
```

The way I was using .load to inject the shopping cart pages in to my dashboard means I obviously wasn't being redirected back to the same URL they came from. It was going straight to the shopping cart page rather than my dashboard page that was loading the shopping cart page inside it.

Feel kind of silly for not seeing it before, but it's fixed! Thanks for the input everyone - super helpful as always :)

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly it is recommended that if you want to submit forms without causing a page load, you would need to use AJAX*.

***Secondly*** if you still intend to use `$.load()` what you can do is have a `data-*` attribute in your button eg say `data-url="your url"`.

```
<input type="submit" data-url="your-url" value="Load" />
```

Now using `jQuery` catch the click event, prevent its default, and load the data with `.attr("data-url")`.

Comment: and duplicating the action of the form in a data attribute is redundant.

Comment: @Quentin Its just for the sake OP has asked for

Answer (score 0):

The action of the form will tell you the URL.

You'll need to express the data in different ways depending on if the form is making a GET or POST request.

Something along the lines of:

```
$("button").on('click', function (e) {
    var $f = $(this.form);
    var data;
    if (f.attr("method").toLowerCase() === "post") {
        data = $f.serializeArray();
    } else {
        data = $f.serialize();
    }
    $("#categories").load(
        $f.attr("action") || location.href,
        data
    );
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

… will probably do the trick, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a test today and report back.